# More complex hand-pose estimation algorithms

Tags: opencv, emgucv, pose-estimation

I am currently looking into hand-pose estimation in Unity without using any expensive plugins! At the moment, I have implemented a simple hand-tracking system by extracting the contours of the hand, like the link below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QE5FcUK5ZA

However, it doesn't work brilliantly in all environments and tends to not recognise the hand when other object are in the frame (like a face!). Does anyone have any more complex algorithms for hand-pose estimation? I've looked at using neural nets but they tend to use a lot of CPU and/or GPU power, and I need this to be lightweight and not lag in Unity.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Just to motivate you, [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/8n04hp/p_realtime_multihand_pose_estimation_demo/).

Comment: Cheers. Have thought of a couple of ideas

Answer (score 0):

Multi-layered random forest is a good light weight method for real time hand pose estimation https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7789644/.

It uses an ensemble of regressors that are specialised on different areas of angle space. And the first layer learns how to weight the output of each of these specialised regressors.

It achieves state of the art on hand pose estimation and has been used by the author in real-time AR applications.

The model uses contour features like the ones you have extracted.